# geoserver and openlayers select rectangle pixel values

Tags: openlayers-2, raster, geoserver, geotiff-tiff

I'm running a geoserver (2.5.x) with 1 raster file (GeoTIFF) as a layer. From my application I can access a single pixel value when clicked (through WMS), but what I'm really interested in is to get a range of pixels and then do some processing on that. The way I was thinking of doing it was to create a control with MOD_CTRL as trigger and then when dragging ended, to pass the selected range to geoserver so that I can get a list of pixel values back.

```
    OpenLayers.Util.extend(control, {
      draw: function () {
          this.drag = new OpenLayers.Handler.Box( control,
              {"done": this.notice},
              {keyMask: OpenLayers.Handler.MOD_CTRL});
          this.drag.activate();
      },

      notice: function (bounds) {
        leftBottom = map.getLonLatFromPixel(new OpenLayers.Pixel(bounds.left, bounds.bottom)); 
        rightTop = map.getLonLatFromPixel(new OpenLayers.Pixel(bounds.right, bounds.top));
        console.log(leftBottom, rightTop);
        return(true);
      }
```

The problem I'm facing is that I can't seem to find a way to pass the "range" (leftBottom,rightTop) to the geoserver - only a single pixel. The leftBottom and rightTop works fine, but how do I get back the list of pixel values?

This function seems to make the call but I'm not sure which service or parameters to use...

```
 function makeCall(bounds) {

   var url = sec.getFullRequestString({
                                          REQUEST: "GetFeature",
                                          SERVICE: "WFS", //should this be WPS?
                                          EXCEPTIONS: "application/vnd.ogc.se_xml",
                                          typeNames: 'mystore:mylayer',
                                          BBOX: bounds.toBBOX(),
                                          INFO_FORMAT: 'text/plain',
                                          QUERY_LAYERS: layerlist,
                                          FEATURE_COUNT: 50,
                                          WIDTH: map.size.w,
                                          HEIGHT: map.size.h,
                                          format: 'image/png',
                                        },
                                        "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs");

    var request = OpenLayers.Request.GET({
      url: url,
      callback: extractFeatures
    });
  }
```

Comment: maybe you could use WCS?

Comment: I have tried that using WCS but I get an error: <ows:Exception exceptionCode="NoApplicableCode">↵    <ows:ExceptionText>java.lang.NullPointerException↵null</ows:ExceptionText>

Comment: looks like you made a bad request - without seeing what you sent its hard to tell.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wcs?LAYERS=mylayer&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&SERVICE=WCS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetCoverage&STYLES=&SRS=EPSG%3A900913&Identifier=mylayer&BBOX=-10537386.459433%2C-3150439.875241%2C15233510.497384%2C4754983.337025&BoundingBox=-10537386.459433%2C-3150439.875241%2C15233510.497384%2C4754983.337025&CRS=EPSG%3A4326&INFO_FORMAT=text%2Fplain&QUERY_LAYERS=mylayer&FEATURE_COUNT=50&WIDTH=1317&HEIGHT=404&format=image%2Fpng

Comment: the describecoverage works and gives me back the valid data

Comment: Not sure that that is a valid WCS request - have a look in the examples

Comment: Does anyone have an example on how to query raster data from a wcs service from openlayers?

Comment: that's probably best asked as a new question

Comment: Do you still have the site: http://ian01.geog.psu.edu.? I would like to see if some of your examples can help me further...

Comment: nope - it died some time ago, but none of those examples would have helped here